# I am getting Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'employeeObj' is not a function, got undefined, and i couldnt figure out what i missed

Tags: angularjs

I am getting Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'employeeObj' is not a function, got undefined, and i couldnt figure out what i missed. Can any body help me?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script>
"use strict"

    function Employee($scope, $rootScope) {
        debugger;
        $rootScope.counter = (($rootScope.counter||0)+1);
        $scope.FirstName = "demo";
        $scope.LastName = "demo";
        $scope.Validate = function () {
            if ($scope.FirstName == 0 || $scope.LastName == 0) {
                alert("No!")
            } else {
                alert("Yes!")
            }
        }
    }
    var empApp = angular.module("employeeApp", []);
    empApp.controller = ("employeeObj", Employee);
</script>
<body>
    <div ng-app="employeeApp">
        <div id="empScreen" ng-controller="employeeObj">
            First Name: <input ng-model="FirstName" id="FirstName" type="text" value=" " /><br />
            Last Name: <input ng-model="LastName" id="LastName" type="text" value=" " /><br />
            {{FirstName}}<br />
            {{LastName}}<br />
            {{counter}}<br />
            <input type="button" value="Validate" ng-click="Validate()" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the version of angular?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this change in controller implementation on the angular part instead:

```
var empApp = angular.module("employeeApp", []);
empApp.controller('employeeObj', Employee); // <-- change here
```

***Before***

```
empApp.controller = ('employeeObj', Employee); <-- remove the equal sign
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using angular version above 1.3 , you need to define controller like this,

```
  var app = angular.module("employeeApp" ,[]);
   app.controller("Employee" , function($scope,$rootScope)
   {
     $rootScope.counter = (($rootScope.counter||0)+1);
        $scope.FirstName = "demo";
        $scope.LastName = "demo";
        $scope.Validate = function () {
            if ($scope.FirstName == 0 || $scope.LastName == 0) {
                alert("No!")
            } else {
                alert("Yes!")
            }
        }
   });
```

[**`DEMO APP`**](https://plnkr.co/edit/p9j5FdlxKi6BZDURN0qC?p=preview)

Comment: @Dalorzo if OP just change the code as you mentioned the app will still return the same error i guess! you need to mention the reason.

Comment: @Dalorzo May be, now you have modified, also the link attached to your answer is not working , initally you just mentioned to change the mentioned line, which obviously won't work. I would not have posted this answer if you have done the changes earlier